# Xamarin Cross Platform Splash Screen on App boot

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, splash-screen

Yo. Some of you might already know but Xamarin Apps are booting pretty slow and the delay occurs before any line of code is executed - at least i figured that out with some breakpoints.
So i want to cover that up using a Splashscreen. But since Xamarin is for multiple platforms i'd like to... welll... use cross platform code. 
The most important part is: i do NOT want to cover my code delay. I want to App to NOT open with a white blank screen like it currently does, but e.g. with an image or some animation or such stuff.

and yes i already googled a little but everything i found seemed to be android specific or iphone stuff, or it just takes affect after the system boots.

Comment: There isn't a cross platform solution.  You need to setup the splash screen for each platform independently.  Any cross-platform solution would only work once XF has loaded, which is what is causing the delay in the first place.  Yo.

Comment: The fact that you have not gotten to the `Xamarin.Forms` init yet, precedes the usage of Forms. Platform-specific "native" splash screens are the solution...

Comment: oh :( sadly i think i have to do it that way. okay thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cross-platform way to do that yet. (Answering in 2017/Dec) 
You'll need to make it for each platform.

**Android**: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/splash-screen/

**iOS**: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/